# Formula in PHPExcel giving FATAL Error

Tags: phpexcel

I am trying to set a formula for age calculation

> =DATEDIF(J2,DATE(2014,3,31),"Y")&" Years, "&DATEDIF(J2,DATE(2014,3,31),"YM")&" Months,
>   "&DATEDIF(J2,DATE(2014,3,31),"MD")&" Days"

in column L which depends on DOB in column J for 1500 columns, my code is like this

```
for($i=2;$i<=1500;$i++){
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$i.',=DATEDIF(J'.$i.',DATE(31-03-2014),"Y") & DATEDIF(J'.$i.',DATE(31-03-2014),"YM") &DATEDIF(J'.$i.',DATE(31-03-2014),"MD")');
}
```

But I am getting this error-

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message
>   'Cell coordinate can not be a range of cells.' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\manazeschool\software\office_admin\exam_excel\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php:1127
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\manazeschool\software\office_admin\exam_excel\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php(1042):
>   PHPExcel_Worksheet->getCell('L2,=DATEDIF(J2,...') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\manazeschool\software\office_admin\exam_excel\excel_export.php(83):
>   PHPExcel_Worksheet->setCellValue('L2,=DATEDIF(J2,...') #2 {main}
>   thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\manazeschool\software\office_admin\exam_excel\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php
>   on line 1127

What mistake I am doing, kindly guide me.

I changed the wrong formula at **setCellValue('L'.$i.',= ...** now it is **setCellValue('L'.$i,'=...**

```
for($i=2;$i<=1500;$i++){ $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$i,'=DATEDIF(J'.$i.',DATE(31-03-2014),"Y") &DATEDIF(J'.$i.',DATE(31-03-2014),"YM") &DATEDIF(J'.$i.',DATE(31-03-2014),"MD")');
}
```

And file got downloaded but Error of file extension of file format file failed to open.

I opened the excel file in notepad and saw the error there I found this message

```
<br/>
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception' with message 'Registration Format!L2 -&gt; Formula Error: Wrong number of arguments for DATE() function: 1 given, 3 expected' in C:\xampp\htdocs\manazeschool\software\office_admin\exam_excel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php:298
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\manazeschool\software\office_admin\exam_excel\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Worksheet.php(1078): PHPExcel_Cell-&gt;getCalculatedValue()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\manazeschool\software\office_admin\exam_excel\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Worksheet.php(1025): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_Worksheet-&gt;_writeCell(Object(PHPExcel_Shared_XMLWriter), Object(PHPExcel_Worksheet), 'L2', Array, Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\manazeschool\software\office_admin\exam_excel\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Worksheet.php(83): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_Worksheet-&gt;_writeSheetData(Object(PHPExcel_Shared_XMLWriter), Object(PHPExcel_Worksheet), Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\manazeschool\software\office_admin\exam_excel\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Exce in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\manazeschool\software\office_admin\exam_excel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php</b> on line <b>298</b><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

After long wait for reply I started exploring for the solution and finally this is the code which solved my problem

```
$date = date('2014,03,31');
for($i=2;$i<=1500;$i++){
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$i,'=DATEDIF(J'.$i.',DATE('.$date.'),"Y") &DATEDIF(J'.$i.',DATE('.$date.'),"YM") &DATEDIF(J'.$i.',DATE('.$date.'),"MD")'); 
}
```

Every user of stackoverflow are not expert we come here for guidance from experts. I waited for 12 hours a any kind of suggestion or help, but no one turn up. It is sad.